# Azure Container App created but not provisioning

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, containers, azure-container-apps

I created a `Azure Container App` but in `Revision Management` status is `Provisioning`.

Below is the log stream:

> Connecting...
> 2023-05-18T09:03:27.45045  Connecting to the container 'mycontainerapp'...
> 2023-05-18T09:03:27.46826  Successfully Connected to container: 'mycontainerapp' [Revision: 'mycontainerapp--76jjdmo', Replica: 'mycontainerapp--76jjdmo-6d96b7b78f-7qfvl']
> 2023-05-18T09:03:06.011996999Z warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
> 2023-05-18T09:03:06.012022639Z       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
> 2023-05-18T09:03:06.029275741Z warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
> 2023-05-18T09:03:06.029286423Z       No XML encryptor configured. Key {14254724-e260-471f-a742-d96c22cb728f} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
> 2023-05-18T09:04:27.84065  No logs since last 60 seconds

Its running in locally as expected with:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name my-container-app mycontainerapp
```

But in the Azure UI I have no where specified `port 5000`.

It is a `Dot Net 7` container. How can I investigate further?

Comment: You haven't stated - but can you confirm if the container runs locally without issue to success? 
IE. Is the problem your container image, or is it ContainerApps.

Comment: Its running as expected with `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name my-container-app mycontainerapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in the Azure UI I have no where specified port 5000.

In the UI, that would be your Target Port on your application's ingress setting.

[image]

Comment: Here, I tried with both `5000` and `443` but no luck, status is `Provisioning` only.

Comment: oops, sorry I misread your docker command. You need that to be `80`. `targetPort` is the port your application is listening on. If your transport type is http/http2, then your exposedPorts are always 80/443.

Comment: `80` is working I wonder for `443`